# How do I set a custom field in Trello using C# and HttpRequestMessage?

Tags: c#, trello

I am able to request the board's cards and custom fields using this code:

---

```
  string qString = @"https://api.trello.com/1/boards/{boardId}/cards?customFieldItems=true&key={myKey}&token={myToken}";
  using(var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), qString))
  {
    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    String JsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

And it returns the information about the cards including the following which tells about my custom field item:

```
   {
    "id": "5f5432b72678573fd5e#####",
     "value": {
       "text": "AAA"
     },
     "idCustomField": "5d24ae4cfe7cb10d611#####",
     "idModel": "5f542e224c5d2c2679d#####",
     "modelType": "card"
   }
```

---

Now I am trying to set the value using the following code:

```
    using(var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
       using(var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PUT"), @"https://api.trello.com/1/cards/" + myCardId + "/" + myCustomFieldId + "/item?" + "key={myKey}&token={myToken}" + "{value: { text: \"New Value\"}}"))
       {
            // i don't know how to set the header content so i commented it out
            //request.Headers.Add("content-type", "application/json");
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            String JsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

---

But it comes back and says it cannot PUT that...

Thanks,
DF

Comment: Can you post the error message ?

Comment: JsonString = Cannot PUT /1/cards/{cardId}/{id}/item?key={key}&token={{token}%7Bvalue:%20%7B%20text:%20%22Help%22%7D%7D

Comment: response = {StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  X-Dns-Prefetch-Control: off
  X-Frame-Options: DENY
  X-Download-Options: noopen
  X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
  Referrer-Polic...

Comment: Cannot PUT /1/cards/{cardId}/{CustomFieldId}/item?key={myKey}&token={myToken}%7Bvalue:%20%7Btext:%20%22TestName%22%7D%7D

Comment: The error I get when I include the commented out line for the header so that I can specify that it is application/json is this: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.'

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.

I was able to figure out my question using this website which converts Curl to C#:

https://curl.olsh.me/

```
private async void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   using(var httpClient = new HttpClient())
   {
       String query = @"https://api.trello.com/1/card/" + myCardId + "/customField/" + myCardsCustomFieldItems_IdCustomField + "/item";
     using(var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PUT"), query))
     {
        request.Content = new StringContent("{  \"value\": { \"text\": \"Hello, world!\" }, \"key\": \"########\",  \"token\": \"#######\" }");
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        String JsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        this.textBox4.Text = query;
        this.richTextBox4.Text = JsonString;
      } 
    }
  }
```